# How to Rename xlsx file with last string

Tags: python, pandas

I have Directory where I have xlsx files and word doc files . I want to rename only xlsx files with last string and today date (dd/mm)

my file path

```
DF_25.xlsx
DF_28.xlsx
DF_30.doc
....
```

my code is below :

```
import os
path = 'H:\Learning\Mohan'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
   os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, 'DF_' + file + '.xlsx'))
```

After executing this all the renaming including Doc and xlsx files .
If I re execute it is keep on appending it should not append in next execute

like this  :

```
DF_DF_25.xlsx.xlsx
DF_DF_28.xlsx.xlsx
DF_DF_30.doc.xlsx
```

I need output like :

```
25_DF_3/5.xlsx
28_DF_3/5.xlsx
DF_30.doc
```

Comment: including `/` in file name is very dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
DF_25.xlsx
DF_28.xlsx
DF_30.doc
```

To

```
25_DF_03_May.xlsx
28_DF_03_May.xlsx
DF_30.doc
```

Use dd_mmm format

_DF is used to check to find the file is already renamed or not

```
import os
from datetime import *
dt=(datetime.today().strftime('%d_%b'))
path = 'H:\Learning\Mohan'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    filename,ext=os.path.splitext(file)
    if ext==".xlsx" and "_DF" not in filename:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, filename.split('_')[-1].strip('.xlsx')+'_DF_'+dt+ext))

print(os.listdir())
```

Comment: it is appending to doc file instead of xlsx file I.e : DF_30.doc_DF_03_May

Comment: Edited now check

Comment: Uncomment the line and run to rename to original name

Comment: can you please run in your environment with sample example you can see the result . it is not giving the expected one

Comment: `DF_25.xlsx
DF_28.xlsx
DF_30.doc` make sure the file are like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192789/discussion-between-mohan111-and-smartmanoj).

Comment: sure let me execute again and get back to you

Comment: @Manoj after execution it is coming like this 1.xlsx_DF_03_May instead of 1_DF_03_May.xlsx

Comment: Would you run the latest code . If any query continue in chat

Comment: I have ran it manoj ...something small is missing apart from that you are bang on the target ...sadly we are getting same result

Comment: what you get `print(*os.listdir(path),sep='\n')` when adding  after and before for loop

Comment: Before  : DF_1.xlsx.xlsx
After  :    1.xlsx_DF_03_May.xlsx

Comment: Remove one .xlsx ; Added Strip

Comment: thank you @smart manoj you are exceptional and very understanding

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.endswith` to check the file extension and the rename the files.

**Ex:**

```
import os
path = 'H:\Learning\Mohan'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, 'DF_' + file))
```

Comment: still it is renaming doc file along with xlsx file and if I re execute it is appending DF_DF_ like this

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Note that I changed slash in 'DD/MM' expression to dot, as slash cannot be use in filename.

```
import os
#IMPORT RE MODULE TO REMOVE ALL NON-NUMERIC SYMBOLS FROM FILE NAME
import re
from datetime import datetime

#DEFINE D/M TO ADD TO NAME
now = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m').replace('0','')

path = 'H:\Learning\Mohan'
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
#CHOOSE ONLY .XLSX FILE
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file)
                 , os.path.join(path, re.sub("[^0-9]", "",file) +'_DF_' + now + '.xlsx'))
```

Comment: Hi kev it is working but if I re execute the script it is keep on appending like this 13535_DF_3.5 what i'm expecting is 1_DF_3.5.xlsx